# process kill notification in linux

Tags: linux, process, embedded-linux, archlinux

Hello I have two process in Linux say P1 & P2 and both are separate executable. 
In process "P1" I'm using "system()" function to run process "P2". 
Process "P2" runs for 6 seconds and it calls "exit()" API ( It kills itself).

I want to know how I can get process "P2" kill notification in Process "P1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P1 will be blocked in system() while P2 executes. The termination of P2 will unblock P1. P1 gets the exit code of P2 as the return value of system.

Comment: Hey Frank, I've used your suggestion and it worked.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

Yes, running system() and than using polling using kill on the process so created, but the Right Thing is to create P2 using fork() and exec() from P1, which would make P1 the parent process of P2 - meaning you will get a SIGCHLD signal when P2 exits.

Comment: Hi gbay, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can not make P2 as child process of P1. P2 process is a re-usable process and it is used by few other modules (process) too.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how I can get process "P2" kill notification in Process "P1"?

`P1` will lock while `P2` executes.

I suggest using `fork()` and `exec()` from P1. That will make `P1` a primary process of `P2`. When `P2` finishes execution it will unlock `P1` pass the return value.

Answer (score -1):

This was pretty simple
I just found that "**int kill (pid_t pid, int signum)**" will work.

Detail of this function can be found below - 
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signaling-Another-Process.html